# Listview footer fix at the bottom of screen when listview items increase

Tags: listview, footer

I have a ListView with a footer added with `listview.addFooterView(footerView);`

All works as expected except in one case: when listview items increase I want footer move till arrive at the bottom of screen and then fix.  Is there a way to do this easily?
Thanks

This is what I want:

[image: This is what I want]